# Adjust audio volume level with CLI omxplayer - Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi2, omxplayer

I have a bash script that plays .mp3 files on my Raspberry Pi via omxplayer. But can not control the local (earphone) audio volume with the **GUI**. Is there a command for the **CLI** that I can implement in the bash script? I have searched quite a bit, but can not find such a command.

Code:

`omxplayer Song_Title.mp3`

Set audio for local (earphone) output:

`sudo modprobe snd_bcm2835
 sudo amixer cset numid=3 1`

`omxplayer -o local`

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

to provide more precise information for playing through scripts, there are 3 ways to change sound volume in current version of omxplayer, and values are not so intuitive:

1. on starting command line, param `--vol YYY`, double millibels, default 0, range [-6000:0]
2. by stdin interface, sending +/- to omxplayer will increase/decrease volume for 300 dmbels
3. with DBUS interface, cmd 'set volume', value `double:XXX`, default 1, range [0:1]

xxx to yyy relation is: `XXX = 10 ^ (YYY / 2000)` ... according to [omxplayer.cpp](https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer/blob/350779b00bb7278e0d1d9025b9ed1ddb4a2d99cd/omxplayer.cpp#L1166) source code, reverse formula would be: `YYY = 2000 * (log XXX)`.

so if we need:

- volume 1%,  XXX=0.01 and YYY=-4000 `(10^(-4000/2000)=10^-2=0.01`
- volume 10%,  XXX=0.1 and YYY=-2000 `(10^(-2000/2000)=10^-1=0.1`
- volume 50%,  XXX=0.5 and YYY=-602  `(10^(-602/2000))~=0.5`
- volume 100%, XXX=1 and YYY=0 `(10^(0/2000)=10^0=1)`
- volume 150%, XXX=1.5 and YYY=352 ... (for boost test, normal values are <=100%)

working bash script for dbus volume command:

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(cat /tmp/omxplayerdbus.${USER:-root})
dbus-send --print-reply --session --reply-timeout=500 \
           --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.omxplayer \
           /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set \
           string:"org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player" \
           string:"Volume" double:0.5   # <-- XXX=0.5 (50% sound volume)
```

equals to volume parameter at startup:

```
omxplayer --vol -602 mediaFileName.mp4
```

... both sets sound volume to 50%.

Comment: very nice explanation

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure how to adjust the volume level with a command. But when using the omxplayer CLI, just press - or + to turn the volume up or down.

Comment: This worked for adjusting the volume level. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Omxplayer doesn't use alsa for sound output, but it's possible to use stdin interface

Volume up:

```
echo -n "+" > /proc/$(pidof omxplayer.bin)/fd/0
```

Volume down:

```
echo -n "-" > /proc/$(pidof omxplayer.bin)/fd/0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the initial volume by adding the option `--vol`:

`omxplayer --vol N Sogn_title.mp3`

Where `N` is a number indicating the millibels. Valid values for N are for example:

5000 (increase the volume)

-15000 (decrease the volume)

Answer (score 1):

In Raspberry Pi 3,
I was able to adjust audio volume through alsamixer.

In the command line 
type

`alsamixer`

you will see 
[image: screen]

Just use up or down arrow to increase or decrease volume.
Press Esc. Volume is set.

Comment: you can ssh directly to `alsamixer` from a smartphone e.g. with `ssh -t pi alsamixer` (where pi is the entry you have in your `~/.ssh/config`). You can also change the volume using vertical swipes on the touchscreen (tested in termux). You can also use the number keys, e.g. `7` to set 70% volume.