# Decrease/Increase omxplayer volume from another terminal

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, omxplayer

After running: omxplayer -o hdmi myVideo.mp4, if I wanna increase/decrease volume, I just have to type + / - Ok. That's working fine. But I have another scenario, can you help me please? **How can I increase/decrease volume from another terminal?** What's the command or **script** that I have to run?

Thanks a lot!

(raspberry pi 3)

Answer (score 0):

You can control `omxplayer` by connecting its `stdin` to a `named pipe`.
As a first step, create a fifo:

```
mkfifo /tmp/omx-control
```

Then start `omxplayer` with its stdin connected to the fifo:

```
omxplayer yourVideo.mp4 < /tmp/omx-control &
```

Now you can control `omxplayer` via the pipe:

```
echo -ne "+" > /tmp/omx-control     # Increase Volume
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, after run "omxplayer -o hdmi Videos/kpop.mp4 < /tmp/omx-control &" I got this: [1] 2323 And the video is not playing

Comment: Try to say `echo -ne p > /tmp/omx-control` after the command above.

Comment: tshiono, thanks. And do you know If it can increase/decrease the volume by quantity? I mean, imagine if I an using a slider control (not a terminal, a user interface) Like doing this echo -ne "+" > /tmp/omx-control  many times in succession.

Comment: And another question please, this *mkfifo /tmp/omx-control* can I create in a permanent way? (not temporal, just one time) I say this because when I reboot my raspberry, I need to do this again mkfifo /tmp/omx-control Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are three ways to control the volume of omxplayer. Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162820/adjust-audio-volume-level-with-cli-omxplayer-raspberry-pi).
As for the stdin interface, there may not be a direct (with absolute value) control. Try instead something like `echo -ne "++++" > /tmp/omx-control` for multiple-time increases (sorry, not tested). Regarding the `named pipe` you can create the fifo wherever you want. For instance try `mkfifo > ~/omx-control` (under home directory) then control with `echo -ne "command" > ~/omx-control`. BR.